# Move multiple registers into a single variable

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, 32-bit

I have a 32-bit number stored in eax and a 32-bit number stored in ebx. I want to combine them into a single 64 bit number defined in section .bss as finalNum, but I'm not sure how. I have tried

```
mov esi, finalNum
mov [esi], eax
add esi, 32
mov [esi], ebx
```

but for some reason when I try to print out the finalNum it's not printing out correctly so I assume there's a problem in these 4 lines. Also this is in 32-bit nasm.

edit:

So I tried

```
    mov esi, finalNum
    mov [esi+0], eax
    mov [esi+4], ebx
```

But, still coming up with some weird print, I declared finalNum as

```
    finalNum:   resb 8
```

do you think this could be an issue?

Edit:

```
    Enter first number to multiply:
    34567
    Enter second number to multiply:
    76543
    First Num: 34567
    Second Num: 76543
    Addition: 111110
    Multiply:
    ▒EAX : 0
    EBX : -1649105415
```

as you see when I multiply and print out I get a weird character.

Edit:
Code to print the result

```
    mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE ; write message
    mov     ebx, STDOUT
    mov     ecx, msg7
    mov     edx, len7
    int     080h

    mov     eax, SYSCALL_WRITE ; write user input
    mov     ebx, STDOUT
    mov     ecx, finalNum
    mov     edx, BUFLENFINAL
    int     080h
```

BUFLENFINAL = 8 by the way

Comment: A "weird print" can be a lot of things. Please post the relevant error message, since the code you presented looks valid.

Comment: Have you looked at the NASM manual, or looked at NASM examples online?

Comment: What is your code to print `finalNum`?

Comment: I've looked up plenty of examples online trying to fix it for the past 8+hours ,but haven't been able to find one that works for my situation.

Comment: Added code to print finalNum

Comment: You're showing the code that calls "print", but you're calling it with a buffer or something that's partially overwritten, or has a non-printable character loaded into it, thus the odd character before `EAX`.

Comment: That's definately an issue but still having same results, i pushed values and popped them after. Actually it's not an issue because it's now stored as finalNum not eax or ebx

Comment: Your use of SYSCALL_WRITE to do the printing doesn't look right. Shouldn't you use a decimal-to-string conversion routine like `printf()`?

Comment: I'm using printf now, push finalNum, push msg5, call printf, but I can't push a 64 bit number

Comment: its a printf %d something I know for sure now I just don't know which one

Answer (score 3):

The lower-order word of the 64-bit number goes in the lower 4 bytes of `finalNum` and the higher-order word goes in the higher 4 bytes of `finalNum`:

```
mov esi, finalNum   ; Load address of where to store 64-bit number
mov [esi+0], eax    ; Store low 32 bits
mov [esi+4], ebx    ; Store high 32 bits
```

Comment: It didn't completely work so I added an edit maybe you could check out

Comment: I'd write "mov esi, offset finalNum" to be clear to the assembler that you want the address.

Comment: when using mov esi, offset finalNum I get the error, error: comma, colon or end of line expected :(

Comment: how would you print it as a single number after this

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
  finalNum:  qword  0

    ....

   mov  dword ptr finalNum, eax
   mov  dword ptr finalNum+4, ebx
```

Comment: qword is in 64 bit though isn't it?

Comment: Yes, qword *means* "64 bit value".  That's exactly what you said you wanted for finalNum, so declare it that way.

Comment: @Alex:  You are using NASM.   I am used to using MASM; the syntax of the instructions may be different for immediate operands.  I may have just added to your confusion;  the "offset" I noted in Nayuki's answer may be wrong for NASM. The answer I wrote here is for MASM syntax, and may not work with NASM.

Comment: Yes but I am in a 32 bit assembler and can only use double words

Comment: MASM32 is a 32 bit assembler.  It has ways to declare QWORDS.   I don't know about NASM.